# Join this us tomorrow

Tags: phrase-meaning

Should "this" be removed from "Join this us tomorrow"? If not, what does the phrase mean? "Join this and join us tomorrow"?

> The BMJ  (British Medical Journal) just tweeted:

WEBINAR: **Join this us tomorrow** at the launch of a new collection on co-producing knowledge for stronger health systems:

Comment: It's certainly a typing error. Yes, _this_ should be deleted.

Comment: Ever so slight contradiction to Kate, I strongly suspect that this is an EDITING error: the original was probably far more verbose, and someone said "too long - take out _that_ bit" and the edit was one word short. She is 100% correct thought that no-one would ever deliberately write it like this.